# -bash: ls: No such file or directory

Tags: bash, shell

I have made a program that acts as a shell and for testing purposes, I try and use the < operator, but receive this error in my bash

the purpose is to take ls as an input and run it in my mock shell

Is there a specific reason I am receiving this error, could it be from my code?

the name of my program is rshell:

```
[xx@xx rshell]$ ./bin/rshell < ls
bash: ls: No such file or directory
```

Comment: Use a pipe to redirect the ouput of `ls`: `ls | ./bin/rshell`

Comment: the syntax u show is to send the contents of a file called ls to /bin/rshell, you dont have one of those, u need ls | xxx

Answer (score 1):

The right-hand side of the input redirection operator `<` requires a filename. So the shell interprets "ls" in your example as a filename. You get an error because there is no such file.

If you want to pass the output of `ls` to your shell, use a pipe:

```
ls | ./bin/rshell
```

Or *process substitution*:

```
./bin/rshell < <(ls)
```

If you want to pass the text "ls" on standard input to your shell, use a here-string:

```
./bin/rshell <<< ls
```

Comment: if I were just to want to pass ls as an argument, would I just do ./bin/rshell ls?

Comment: Yes, `./bin/rshell ls` would pass "ls" as an argument

Comment: that would make ls a command argument no?
Im trying to get ls and other strings to be injected into ./bin/rshell as if I typed them inmyself

Comment: @opera97 I updated my post with a 3rd variant that you might be looking for. (It's not very clear what you're trying to do...)

Answer (score 0):

The syntax you have, `./bin/rshell < ls`, means "read from a file named 'ls'".

If you are trying to send the output of the `ls` **command** into /bin/rshell, you need to either pipeline it with a pipe:

```
ls | ./bin/rshell
```

or read from an anonymous filehandle:

```
./bin/rshell < <(ls)
```

Basically, `>` and `<` are for dealing with files (file i/o), and `|` is what you want for dealing with passing output from one command to another (command i/o); but, you can combine the two with anonymous filehandles using the `<(command)` syntax.

Inside of a shell script, you can do fancier things, such as storing the output of a command in a string variable, then using that string as input, parsing it up, and all kinds of fun stuff.  First things first, though.

An excellent resource for learning all things bash is the Advanced Bash-Scripting Guide: http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/index.html

Comment: Thank you,  now I see I was using this in the wrong context, i was trying o pass ls as a string that would a t as if i entered la myself in the program

Comment: after input redirection, will i be able to input commands from the keyboard?

Comment: @opera97 Also see the [bash hackers wiki](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/) for a lot of good information